# How to add <audio> tag to Content of Page in Code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, htmlcontrols

I want to add this audio html tag to the page from code behind in `Client.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`. Is it possible?

```
<audio id="A"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player = document.getElementById("A");
    function Alert() {
        player.preload = 'auto';
        player.src = "/Sounds/tada.wav";
        player.play();
    }
</script>
```

**BaseClass**

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreRender(e);

  //add audio tag 

}

}
```

**Page.aspx**

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"  runat="server">
 ....
 .....
 ....
</asp:Content>
```

**Page.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Page: BasePage
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  }

}
```

Comment: could you please tell us what u want to achive?

Comment: I want to do this in code behind by Client.RegisterClientScriptBlock().<audio id="A"></audio>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var player = document.getElementById("A");
        function Alert() {
            player.preload = 'auto';
            player.src = "/Sounds/tada.wav";

            player.play();
        }
    </script>

Comment: Side note: "from code behind" usually means in C# code, "in RegisterClientScriptBlock" usually means in JavaScript... Please clarify what exactly you have problem with as C# answers provided don't seem to satisfy you.

Answer (score 3):

`<audio>` tag? or `<html>` tag?

`<audio>` tag you should be able to add with

```
var ctrl = new HtmlGenericControl("audio");
myContainer.Add(ctrl);
```

where myContainer is a container in your template (eg a div)

For the javascript part, you would need to reference the client id of the audio ctrl in your javascript. You could build up your javascript in the backend, or just build up a javascript property in the backend and put it into the template.

```
var scriptText = String.Format("var audioId = {0};", ctrl.ClientId);
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", scriptText, true);
```

and then in your javascript in the template

```
var player = document.getElementById(audioId);
```

Comment: Good answer... Any thoughts on the JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var myAudio = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAudio();
myAudio.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
myAudio.Attributes.Add("controls", "controls");
myAudio.Src = "test.mp3";
Form.Controls.Add(myAudio);
```

Comment: Sir .wav file is not playing when function is calling. http://pastie.org/private/zs6pryra3my3x1wpnspcag

Comment: check for browser support. wav is supported by firefox n safari only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats