# How to add value-less HTML5 attributes from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is a follow up of this question: [How to add <audio> tag to Content of Page in Code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29852325/17447)

Here I am creating an `audio` control like this.

```
var myAudio = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAudio();
myAudio.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
myAudio.Attributes.Add("controls", "controls");
myAudio.Src = "test.mp3";
Form.Controls.Add(myAudio);
```

This renders in page as

```
<audio src="test.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls"></audio>
```

It works. But ideally, I would like this to be rendered as

```
<audio src="test.mp3" autoplay controls></audio>
```

That is, as a valueless attribute with just the keys `autoplay` and `controls`.

I tried

```
myAudio.Attributes.Add("autoplay", ""); //autoplay = "";
myAudio.Attributes.Add("autoplay", null); //autoplay attribute missing
```

But these didn't yield any satisfactory results.

Is there a way to render the control with valueless attributes?

Comment: Is there a particular reason it has to be valueless?

Comment: Is this preference of source rendering? According to the HTML5 spec, it only matters if these attributes are present - the values are not taken into account.

Comment: no particular reason. that way code will be cleaner. I would like to know if there is a way. thats all

Comment: @naveen I've added "webfroms" tag as it looks like it what you are using - please check. Note that it would be trivial in ASP.Net MVC Razor... With WebForms I think you are stuck with custom rendering of the control...

Comment: Have you tried TagBuilder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to override the `RenderAttributes` method on an inherited control.

```
public class MyCustomAudio : System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAudio
{
    protected override void RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (string key in this.Attributes.Keys)
        {
            String val = this.Attributes[key];
            writer.Write(val == key
                ? String.Format(" {0}", key)
                : String.Format(" {0}=\"{1}\"", key, val));
        }
    }
}
```

With your same code:

```
var myAudio = new MyCustomAudio();
myAudio.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
myAudio.Attributes.Add("controls", "controls");
myAudio.Src = "test.mp3";
Form.Controls.Add(myAudio);
```

I got this output:

```
<audio autoplay controls src="test.mp3"></audio>
```